# How can I suppress warnings from a Perl function?

Tags: perl, error-handling

In PHP you might use `@` in front of function call to suppress warnings returned.

Is there something similar in Perl?

Comment: There is often a right way and a wrong way to do things -- This is one of the wrong ways. The better question is: *How do I use this function correctly, so that I do not get warnings?*

Comment: If you need to call somebody else's faulty function, you don't actually have a choice.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This feature of PHP is crazy and should be avoided whenever possible.

Perl has two kinds of exceptions: Fatal errors and warnings. Warnings may either be emitted by Perl itself, or by user code.

Inside a certain static/lexical scope, Perl's builtin warnings can be switched off like:

```
use warnings;

foo();

sub foo {
  no warnings 'uninitialized';  # recommended: only switch of specific categories
  warn "hello\n";
  1 + undef;  # Otherwise: Use of uninitialized value in addition (+)
}
```

Output: `hello` on STDERR.

(A list of all warnings categories can be found [here](https://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html#Category-Hierarchy) )

But this can't be used to remove warnings from code you are *calling* (dynamic scope). This also doesn't silence user-defined warnings.

In this case, you can write a handler for the `__WARN__` pseudo-signal:

```
use warnings;
{
  local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub { };
  foo();
  print "bye\n";
}

sub foo {
  warn "hello\n";
  1 + undef;
}
```

Output: `bye` on STDOUT.

We can abstract that into a function `muffle`:

```
sub muffle {
  my $func = shift;
  local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub { };
  return $func->(@_);
}

muffle(\&foo, 1, 2, 3); # foo(1, 2, 3)
```

However, this is an incredibly dumb thing to do:

- Warnings point to potential problems and bugs. Fix those instead of ignoring them.
- Don't activate built-in warnings in the first place for categories you aren't interested in. E.g. many people are perfectly happy that an `undef` value stringifies to the empty string, and don't want any warning for that.

The strategies outlined here do not handle fatal exceptions, use [`Try::Tiny`](https://metacpan.org/module/Try::Tiny) instead.

Comment: btw, what is a reason why warnings can't be silenced by localising STDERR? `perl -e 'local *STDERR; warn 4'`

Comment: @mpapec Interesting … I'd wager the guess that `warn` and builtin warnings do not look up the `*main::STDERR` symbol when executed, and they just print to the file handle directly. But re-opening the file handle works fine… Maybe somebody knows the answer when you post this as a proper question here. I'm curious.

Comment: tnx amon, I've posted separate question

Comment: Maybe emphasise more that it's an incredibly dumb thing to do.

Answer (score 3):

You could also just run `perl -X` and disable all warnings.

I think there are perfectly valid reasons for doing this FWIW.

Comment: Quite right, such as when you're working on production code that emits unnecessary or not-very-useful warnings that haven't been cleaned up yet. Or to test whether you've written something somewhere that is creating a ton of warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Easier way is to use `no warnings;` See [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) link for more information. Wrap the statement giving warning in curly braces to get rid of the warning message.

E.g.

```
{
     no warnings;
     <statement giving warning>
}
```